# Is it possible to create a "Private" CFQL Method?

Tags: codefluent

Is it possible to create a "Private" CFQL Method?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you trying to abuse the system, but using filler to ignore our guidelines.  Stackoverflow is not a forum, If you want a yes or no answer you can check out chats.  Or attempt to answer the question you're self and post the code you've come up with

Comment: I disagree. It's not about trying to abuse the system. Sometimes a question only requires one sentence to ask. People want short questions that provide all the details needed to answer the question. That is what I provided, nothing more & nothing less. Codefluent Entities is a modeling tool, in this case there is no code I could have shown and asked people what I am doing wrong. Who would want just a yes/no answer when asking if something is possible? Please restore my reputation points.

Comment: I still think it would have been possible to meet the requirements without writing nonsense in the question.  However, seeing as a moderator has view the question, I will assume they've handle it properly, So I will retract my downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. On the method properties I set the Member Attributes to "Private".

[image]